# I used 'Erase All Content and Settings' on the xCode simulator and now my app doesn't show up

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm creating a project using xCode9.4 and everything was working fine. My app started to update without the changes in the code so I (stupidly) used the Hardware>Erase All Content and Settings option. Now the icon for my app won't appear at all. I've tried deleting the build folder and rebuilding and I've tried restarting the device. I'm not entirely sure what erasing and resetting did so I don't know what to do to fix it. Any suggestions would be great! Thanks!

Comment: you can try delete that simulator and add it again

Comment: I tried that. I've deleted and reinstalled everything I can think of.